# Creates Charts with integrated tables following MS Office?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I need to create a chart following the template from MS Office.
if anyone knows of an existing JS library or how to make create charts with tabular data attached to the bottom, please help me.

[image template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OuGV.png)

Comment: start by looking at MS Office developer docs to see how this can be done. Right now, you have a very generic question that is hard to answer.

Comment: You could try the https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html library